# Protractor doesn't detect assertion functionallty

Tags: javascript, automation, jasmine, protractor

I'm using node 0.12.10
and I've installed protractor 2.0

When writing a simple test using WebStrom the assertion functions are not detected and I'm getting **TypeError: undefined is not a function** exception when trying to use .toBe(boolean) and such. In WebStorm these functions are marked as **unresolved functions**.

```
describe('New Account Test', function() {
  it('Add Account', function() {

      element(by.name('btnNewAccount')).click().then(function () {
          var submit = element(by.name('createAccount'));

          expect(submit.isElementPresent().toBe(false)); // FAIL

          element(by.name('firstName')).sendKeys('A');
          element(by.name('lastName')).sendKeys('B');

          expect(submit.isEnabled().toBe(true));

          })
    });

});
```

Answer (score 1):

The syntax of expect statement you are using is incorrect. it should be like below,

```
 expect(submit.isPresent()).toBe(false);
```

And

```
 expect(submit.isEnabled()).toBe(true);
```